# Can't build docker image from github repository branch

Tags: github, docker, branch, docker-build

I have a private GitHub repository containing 2 branches: `master` and `stage`.
Repository contains a `Dockerfile` and other files necessary to build a container image.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) I can specify the branch when calling docker build command.

However, I am able to run:

```
sudo docker build -t="superimage" https://github.com/organization/repo.git
```

After this I am asked for my GitHub login and password.

But when I try to run:

```
https://github.com/organization/repo.git#stage
```

I am getting:

```
Error: Got HTTP status code >= 400: 404 Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Docker?

Comment: Docker version 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the changelog (https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#170-2015-06-16) the building of specific git branches appears to be a feature introduced in 1.7. You'll need to upgrade to 1.7+ to get this functionality.